# Addition of numbers with same base but different exponents

Tags: exponentiation

The problem itself is $(288\sqrt{3})^{1/5}+(288\sqrt{3})^{4/5}$. The answer is supposed to be of the form $a+b\sqrt{c}$, but I have no idea how to simplify it.

Comment: It will probably help to know that $288=2^5\cdot 3^2$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Note that $288\sqrt3=2^5\cdot3^{5/2}$, so the first term is simply $2\sqrt3$. Now what’s the second term?

Comment: @user79199: Yes: $\left(2\sqrt3\right)^4=2^4\cdot3^2=144$.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user79199: You’re welcome.